# How to upload files using NSURLSessionStreamTask via FTP in IOS 9.1

Tags: objective-c, ftp, nsurlsession

I am attempting to upload CSV files to the FTP server using NSURLSessionStreamTask but it doesn't work.
Here is my code;

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

NSString *uploadURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ftp://%@:%@@%@", userName,password,IP];

NSURLSessionStreamTask *streamTask = [session streamTaskWithHostName:uploadURL port:21];

[streamTask writeData:pathData timeout:60.0 completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
    NSLog(@"error");
    }
[streamTask closeWrite];
[streamTask stopSecureConnection];
return;
 }

NSLog(@"success");
[streamTask closeWrite];
[streamTask stopSecureConnection];
 }];
  }
   [streamTask resume];
}
```

And I got this error message;

```
Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=2 "(null)" UserInfo={kCFGetAddrInfoFailureKey=8
```

If you can give me any advice or tips, please tell me.
I would really appreciate it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would like to share this post. https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/105344#105344

Answer (score 1):

It'll probably help if you fill the first argument of `streamTaskWithHostName: port:` with a **hostname**!  You give it a URL.  There's no compile-time error because you passed the URL as a `NSString` (instead of a `NSURL`).  You don't need the `uploadURL` variable; pass in `IP` instead.

The point of the `NSURLSessionStreamTask` is that you do all of the protocol transactions yourself, using the rest of the `NSURLSession` system when handling protocols not-in/different-from Apple's default handlers.  In other words, this code won't do the FTP transactions for you; you have to build and send the commands yourself.  This case includes uploading the username and password information.

Comment: Um, you said the same thing I did.